# Create a conditional for an ISO 8601 date using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

For example I have this format: 2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1000, how would I create a conditional block to check if a certain string matches the aforementioned format using momentjs?

```
var string1 = '2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1000';
var string2 = '2003-09-25T14:00';

if (string1 === 'moment format check') // true
if (string2 === 'moment format check') // false
```

It's similar to like if in PHP for example 2018-01-12 === date('Y-m-d') or 2018-1-12 10:28:30 !== date('Y-m-d') in a pseudo-code logic (of course this doesn't work when you run it exactly like that) but hopefully my point is established.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) you can do something like this:

`moment("2010 11 31", "YYYY MM DD").isValid();  // false (not a real day)`

`isValid()` will return false if the string doesn't match the specified format.

For your example string should be:

`moment("2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1000", "YYYY-M-DTH:m:s.SSSZ", true).isValid()`

the third parameter enforces strict parsing.

Comment: It's actually a great answer! I just need a little more to get this..

On my test: 2003-09-25T14:00:00.000+1000 to true BUT
2003-09-25T14:00:00.000Z also validates to true. Is there a way to validate only the first format as true, and false on the second?